# How to calculate convolutional filter size in python keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a sample code from somewhere on the Internet.
It's a part of simple CNN+GAN modeling code in python3.6, keras.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.img_rows = 28
    self.img_cols = 28
    self.channels = 1

def build_discriminator(self):
    img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5), strides=(2,2),\
    padding='same', input_shape=img_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5),strides=(2,2)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    return model
```

It actually works but I don't still get why this filter size comes with (5,5) here.
Because the image size is 28*28, and strides are set as (2,2), and padding must be 1 each by `"padding='same'"`.
So the filter size has to be (4,4) instead of (5,5)?
Can anyone explain the reason for the filter size? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you saying it should be (4,4)? The filter size is a parameter, you can set it to either value.

Comment: When ```padding=1, strides=2```, I guess ```filter size = - (self.img_rows - (self.img_rows+(padding*2)) - strides)``` makes sense. so here ```filter size = -(28 - (30) -2)``` and it should be 4? otherwise this thing probably happens: https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/b7f0ae1bc72e50e000a21b66dca10b65eb0457d1/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f32353939302f38363936353336302d306164382d363034382d353930662d3239346661353039326536372e706e67

Answer (score 0):

this post explains very well why we use odd numbers in filters for conv layers.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23183/why-convolutions-always-use-odd-numbers-as-filter-size

A very fast explanation (but not complete) would be: the filter needs to hava a center, wich is not possible with even numbers kernel like (4,4).

Comment: Thanks! the idea of source pixel is pretty convincing. but what if it's out of the container(orignal image size + padding) and it cannot scan the edge because of too big filter size? https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/b7f0ae1bc72e50e000a21b66dca10b65eb0457d1/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f32353939302f38363936353336302d306164382d363034382d353930662d3239346661353039326536372e706e67

Comment: The kernel centers itself on the pixels so the edge will be scanned anyway. https://buzzrobot.com/whats-happening-inside-the-convolutional-neural-network-the-answer-is-convolution-2c22075dc68d

Comment: When we use model.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5),strides=(2,2))) we tell keras to use 128 filters. But what filters does it use? How does it calculate those filters?

Comment: @skan your response is here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16463/what-is-are-the-default-filters-used-by-keras-convolution2d 
but shortly it is set randomly first then adjusted during the training

Comment: Thank you @AdForte. Then those filters add a new set of parameters that also need to be optimized along with the weights.